# Dojo to jQuery conversion

Tags: jquery, dojo

I have a requirement to convert dojo to jQuery, for that I need to prepare analysis report.
Mentioning about time required and complicity to convert. Detailed case study. If any detailed document is available about dojo to jQuery conversion, please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight forward solution.

Dojo to jQuery conversion is not single step case, while conversion you can do part by part approach and you can have both dojo and jQuery co-exist.

Do you think, do you really need to do? Dojo is a complete toolsuite, while jQuery is a simple framework for small websites.

Please see.

http://www.slideshare.net/AddyOsmani/tools-for-jquery-application-architecture-extended-slides
and
http://www.slideshare.net/rmurphey/the-jquery-divide-5287573

jQuery can do what dojo has but again you need to set the complete architecture to get things for it. Which says, you already have a proper fully loaded advanced kit and you want to redesign from scratch and build your needs. Following your new architecture can be even end-up tricky and worse than both the frameworks documents.

Kindly think before you proceed.